# Styles on a div-element are applied on the button inside the div

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to adjust the width of a div-element but it's affecting the button inside instead of the div itself. Here's my Code:

```
<div class="contentbox" id="block-upload" style="width: 300px; position: relative;">
<div class="legende">"Uploads"</div>
<button type="button" name="upload" value="Datei-Upload" style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px;">Testbutton</button>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: Resulting contentbox and button]

It looks like it's caused by the 'position'-styles I put on the div and the button but I don't understand why and how to fix it. I need my button to be at the bottom of the div and I need my div to be a certain width so any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I imagine the biggest problem is the invalid HTML that's causing the browser to (unpredictably) 'rescue' your document when constructing the DOM. A `<tr>` element can only appear as a child of a `<table>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>` or `<thead>`; a `<div>` cannot appear inside of a `<table>` *unless* it's wrapped in a `<td>` or `<th>`. First correct - and validate - your HTML, and then see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: oh whoops I copy pasted that part and forgot to remove those so thank you BUT it still doesn't work (I simply removed both td/tr lines)

Comment: Then please update the code snippet you have shown accordingly. And you need to give us a _proper_ explanation, of what the actual problem is supposed to be here. What has changed, and what do you _want_ this to look like? Please go read [ask].

Comment: Removing the width from the outer container, and/or the position from either or both places, does not appear to change anything about how the button itself displays. (Since it doesn’t have any content, that is just very small.) It is just massively unclear, what the problem is supposed to be here.

Comment: I've updated the code and included a screenshot that hopefully clarifies my problem. Only the button is being affected by the width-styling, not the contentbox itself on which the style is applied.

Comment: How do you know the content box width hasn't been affected? The only other content it has appears to be the div with class legende - and we don't know what that sets. Are you in some sort of grid layout?

Comment: Because if I define a background-color for it I can tell that it hasn't (even if I fill it with other content) and no I'm not in any kind of grid layout.

Comment: It works just fine in Firefox, just not in Chrome so that's a start